# Can't center Li inside Ul

Tags: html, css

```
.container                          {width: 1280px;min-height: 100%;margin: 0 auto;border: 1px solid #fff;}
.nav-icon                           {display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}

.navigation                         {text-align: center;}
.bans                               {background: url('http://i.imgur.com/iAUP7gR.png');width: 156px;height: 85px;float: left;display:inline-block;margin-left: 21px;margin-right: 21px;}
.shop                               {background: url('http://i.imgur.com/4x7gr4h.png');width: 155px;height: 85px;float: left;display:inline-block;margin-left: 21px;margin-right: 21px;}
.vote                               {background: url('http://i.imgur.com/WPZnkFV.png');width: 160px;height: 59px;float: left;display:inline-block;margin-left: 21px;margin-right: 21px;margin-top: 11px;}
.leaderboard                        {background: url('http://i.imgur.com/ygQlMaN.png');width: 394px;height: 85px;float: left;display:inline-block;margin-left: 21px;margin-right: 21px;}
```

Im using that to try and Center Multiple Li's inside of the Ul...

```
<ul>
    <li><a href=""><div class="bans"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="shop"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="vote"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="leaderboard"></div></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why do you need child div's? You can style LI same way

Comment: Try This http://jsfiddle.net/4R6WK/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on nicole101's answer:

```
CSS
.navigation{
text-align: center;
}
HTML
<div class='navigation'>
<ul>
    <li><a href=""><div class="bans"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="shop"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="vote"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="leaderboard"></div></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Then it will be centered

Comment: don't use `float:left;`

Comment: i did some edit. but i don't know where the red shadow comes from

Comment: red shadow is basically a background color used on `li` .

Answer (score 2):

Even simplier, don't use child div's at all, since you can style LI as you want. And you don't want useless elements. Not good for optimization.

EDITED: since TS needed a menu..

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

**SCSS**

```
ul {
    background: green;
    width: 450px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    li {
        width: 70px;
        height: 50px;
        background: red;
        margin: 0 10px;
        float: left;
    }   
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LfHNZ/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean?

```
ul.mylist li{
    float:left;   
    display:inline;
    margin:0px 10px;
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/lotusms/eS8G9/1/)

Comment: Why would you want it display inline? You asked for it centered? Did you mean, you want it horizontally displayed?

Comment: which means you don't understand inline property. I'll update my answer for your needs

Comment: So you want it hhorizontal, not centered

Comment: Thankyou for that :), Horizontal and centered at the sametime, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Twipply that's called **horizontally centered**, you can use that phrase instead in future.

Answer (score 1):

Try this css

```
ul li a{display:block;text-align:center;}
ul li div{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4R6WK/)**

### ----------------

**Updated css**

```
ul li a{display:block;text-align:center;}
ul li div{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;}

.bans{background: url('http://i.imgur.com/iAUP7gR.png');width: 156px;height: 85px;}
.shop{background: url('http://i.imgur.com/4x7gr4h.png');width: 155px;height: 85px;}
.vote {background: url('http://i.imgur.com/WPZnkFV.png');width: 160px;height: 59px;}
.leaderboard{background: url('http://i.imgur.com/ygQlMaN.png');width: 394px;height: 85px;}
```

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4R6WK/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

I've removed the unnecessary div inside the li. you may remove the unnecessary div inside `li`. to make the `ul items` center on parent div I've added the `text-align:center` it will center the `ul` on the page.

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="mylist">
<li><a href="" class="bans"></a></li>
<li><a href="" class="shop"></a></li>
<li><a href="" class="vote"></a></li>
<li><a href="" class="leaderboard"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and Here is the CSS.

```
.container
{
width: 1280px;
min-height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
border: 1px solid #fff;
text-align: center; /*this line will made the center horizontally*/
}

ul.mylist
{
margin:0 auto;
width:100%;
}

ul.mylist li{display:inline-block;}
```

Here is the **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/navamehe/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

use 
    align:center;
on your divs rather than using it on the li

Comment: @nicole, align center is more defining to text. Th risk you run by using it, is that the text in it will lose its natural left alignment. Meanwhile margin: 0 auto distributes the left and right margin equally within the space and leaving all internal texts in its proper allignement as intendd

Comment: you didn't even use the navigation class. try using it on the <ul>, <ul class="navigation">

Comment: The OP didn't intend that. That class could be for anything and if that is the way the navigation was supposed to be classed it is wrong as well. No text-align:center should be used to position anything. It is not a positioning property

Comment: if what you're trying to center is the divs, use margin:0 auto like they said. sorry. I thought you're trying to center paragraphs inside the div.